# Find single column indices

Tags: mysql, indexing, information-schema

I'm trying to find out whether a certain column is indexed (by itself). In other words, I don't want to pull indices that are multi-column.

Can someone assist me in rewriting this to only pull single-column index?

```
select table_name, index_name 
from information_schema.statistics 
where table_schema='schema' and table_name='table' and column_name='column';
```

Answer (score 0):

You can group the indices by their name in a sub query and then select the ones which are unique.

```
select index_name from
    (select index_name, COUNT(*) as col_count
    from information_schema.statistics
    where table_schema='schema' and table_name='table'
    group by index_name) as sub
where col_count = 1
```

---

You might want to add `column_name` to the inner and outer `select`-list; and to the outer `where`-condition. This will probably work in this case, because of the condition `col_count = 1`, but in general having a trivial column (not using `COUNT`, `MAX`, ...) in the `select`-list which is not listed in the `group`-statement, leads to unpredicted behavior, cf. [sql antipattern](https://www.slideshare.net/billkarwin/sql-antipatterns-strike-back/127-Ambiguous_Groups_Please_accept_my).

Comment: This doesn't work. This still lists all indices that have that column name in it, regardless if it is a single of multi-column index.

Comment: Yes, sorry, I made a mistake, when I copied the query from my test env to SO. You should drop `and column_name='column'` in the inner query. I have updated the answer. If you already specify the `column_name`, then there are no other columns left to `COUNT`.

Comment: Do you still experience problems with this solution?

Answer (score 0):

Rewritten without the sub-select...

This will return the table and index name for a particular index where it is on a single (unspecified) column

```
SELECT table_name, index_name 
FROM information_schema.statistics 
WHERE table_schema='schema' 
AND table_name='table' 
AND index_name = 'index' 
GROUP BY table_name, index_name 
HAVING COUNT(*) = 1;
```

This is the same for all single column indexes in a given table

```
SELECT table_name, index_name 
FROM information_schema.statistics 
WHERE table_schema='schema' 
AND table_name='table' 
GROUP BY table_name, index_name 
HAVING COUNT(*) = 1;
```

Finally, all single column indexes in a given database

```
SELECT table_name, index_name 
FROM information_schema.statistics 
WHERE table_schema='schema' 
GROUP BY table_name, index_name 
HAVING COUNT(*) = 1;
```